# Parse Full Name Field Oracle

Tags: parsing, oracle10g

I was wondering if anyone could help me with parsing a full name field.
I would like to separate it into lastname, firstname, middle initial, suffix.

Here are some inputs for name followed by how I would like for them to be parsed.

```
                           Parsed Stuff Begins Here-------------------------------------
    name                  | lastname  | firstname        |  middle initial   | suffix |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PUBLIC, JOHN              | PUBLIC    | JOHN             |  NULL             | NULL
PUBLIC, CHUN CH KIM       | PUBLIC    | CHUN CH KIM      |  NULL             | NULL
PUBLIC, MARY L            | PUBLIC    | MARY             |  L                | NULL
PUBLIC, FRED J JR         | PUBLIC    | FRED             |  J                | JR
PUBLIC, SUE ELLEN J SR    | PUBLIC    | SUE ELLEN        |  J                | SR
```

I have a list of all the suffix values that one is able to enter, i.e.

```
JR, SR, I,II,III,IV,V,VI
```

I've gotten to a point where I split up the lastname and the rest of the name,
but I can't quite figure out how to do the rest.
I'm using oracle 10g.

***This is not a homework question.  It's an actual problem I'm working on at work.***

Here's what I currently have:

```
 select id,
        name,
        substr(name,1, instr(name,',')-1) as lname,
        substr(name,(instr(name,',')+1),length(name)) as rest_of_the_name
 from    my_table
 where status='A';
```

Comment: it might help if you show us what you have, not just the problem statement.  i repeat the 'is this homework' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've partially solved it already - you can use your query as a subquery and break the problem down bit by bit, e.g.:

```
select id, name, lname,
       case
       when substr(x, -2, 1) = ' '
       then substr(x, length(x) - 2)
       else x
       end as first_name, -- e.g. "SUE ELLEN"
       case
       when substr(x, -2, 1) = ' ' 
       then substr(x, -1)
       else null
       end as middle_initial, -- e.g. "J"
       suffix -- e.g. "SR"
from (
select id, name, lname, suffix,
       case when suffix is not null then
       substr(rest_of_the_name, 1, length(rest_of_the_name)-length(suffix)-1)
       else rest_of_the_name end
       as x -- e.g. "SUE ELLEN J"
from (
select id, name, lname, rest_of_the_name,
       case
       when substr(rest_of_the_name,-2)
            in (' I',' V')
       then substr(rest_of_the_name,-1)
       when substr(rest_of_the_name,-3)
            in (' JR',' SR',' II',' IV',' VI')
       then substr(rest_of_the_name,-2)
       when substr(rest_of_the_name,-4)
            in (' III')
       then substr(rest_of_the_name,-3)
       else null
       end as suffix -- e.g. "SR"
from (
select id,
       name, --e.g. "PUBLIC, SUE ELLEN J SR"
       trim(substr(name,1, instr(name,',')-1)) as lname, -- e.g. "PUBLIC"
       trim(substr(name,(instr(name,',')+1),length(name)))
          as rest_of_the_name -- e.g. "SUE ELLEN J SR"
from    my_table
where status='A'
)));
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffery!
I've altered the query just a bit and i ended up with a solution that works for most of the names in our db.

Comment: You may find you'll have to keep changing it quite a bit depending on the consistency of the data - to the point where it will be easier to use a procedural solution.

Comment: Jeffrey Kemp mentioned the OP might need a procedural solution. Is there any chance someone's already created one?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem for which there will always be data that breaks it.

What if there are 2 initials? What if the initials are first, as J Edgar Hoover?

You mention values "that one is able to enter." Can you change the way the values are entered to capture them already separated?

Comment: yeah we are planning to change the way they are entered so that they are all captured in different field, but there are around 5 million names that currently exist which need to be parsed.

Comment: +1 for the best suggestion - to try to capture the values separated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an unsophisticated answer, based on the retrieving the first and last name, retrieving the MI the same way as the first name, removing the MI from 'rest_of_the_name' as the last name.

```
SELECT
substr('John Q. Public',1, instr('John Q. Public',' ')-1) as FirstName,
substr('John Q. Public',(instr('John Q. Public',' ')+1),length('John Q. Public')) as rest_of_the_name,
substr(substr('John Q. Public',(instr('John Q. Public',' ')+1),length('John Q. Public')),1, instr(substr('John Q. Public',(instr('John Q. Public',' ')+1),length('John Q. Public')),' ')-1) as MI,
replace(substr('John Q. Public',(instr('John Q. Public',' ')+1),length('John Q. Public')), substr(substr('John Q. Public',(instr('John Q. Public',' ')+1),length('John Q. Public')),1, instr(substr('John Q. Public',(instr('John Q. Public',' ')+1),length('John Q. Public')),' ')-1)) as LastName
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This post contained a pretty complete SQL-only solution, written in SQLServer syntax. I've converted it to Oracle syntax.  It does a pretty good job, though it doesn't handle suffixes (Jr., III, etc). You should read the other caveats in the post:

[SQL: parse the first, middle and last name from a fullname field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/sql-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-fullname-field)

```
SELECT first_name.original_input_data,
       first_name.title,
       first_name.first_name,
       CASE
           WHEN 0 = INSTR(first_name.rest_of_name, ' ') THEN
            NULL --no more spaces?  assume rest is the last name
           ELSE
            SUBSTR(first_name.rest_of_name, 1, INSTR(first_name.rest_of_name, ' ') - 1)
       END AS middle_name,
       SUBSTR(first_name.rest_of_name,
              1 + INSTR(first_name.rest_of_name, ' '),
              LENGTH(first_name.rest_of_name)) AS last_name
  FROM (SELECT title.title,
                CASE
                    WHEN 0 = INSTR(title.rest_of_name, ' ') THEN
                     title.rest_of_name --No space? return the whole thing
                    ELSE
                     SUBSTR(title.rest_of_name, 1, INSTR(title.rest_of_name, ' ') - 1)
                END AS first_name,
                CASE
                    WHEN 0 = INSTR(title.rest_of_name, ' ') THEN
                     NULL --no spaces @ all?  then 1st name is all we have
                    ELSE
                     SUBSTR(title.rest_of_name, INSTR(title.rest_of_name, ' ') + 1, LENGTH(title.rest_of_name))
                END AS rest_of_name,
                title.original_input_data
           FROM (SELECT
                  --if the first three characters are in this list,
                  --then pull it as a "title".  otherwise return NULL for title.
                   CASE
                       WHEN SUBSTR(test_data.full_name, 1, 3) IN ('MR ', 'MS ', 'DR ', 'MRS') THEN
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(test_data.full_name, 1, 3)))
                       ELSE
                        NULL
                   END AS title
                   --if you change the list, don't forget to change it here, too.
                 --so much for the DRY prinicple...
                ,
                 CASE
                     WHEN SUBSTR(test_data.full_name, 1, 3) IN ('MR ', 'MS ', 'DR ', 'MRS') THEN
                      LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(test_data.full_name, 4, LENGTH(test_data.full_name))))
                     ELSE
                      LTRIM(RTRIM(test_data.full_name))
                 END AS rest_of_name,
                 test_data.original_input_data
                  FROM (SELECT
                        --trim leading & trailing spaces before trying to process
                        --disallow extra spaces *within* the name
                         REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(full_name)), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' ') AS full_name,
                         full_name AS original_input_data
                          FROM ( --if you use this, then replace the following
                                --block with your actual table
                                SELECT 'george w bush jr.' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT 'SUSAN B ANTHONY' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT 'alexander hamilton' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT 'osama bin laden jr' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT 'Martin J. VAN BUREN SENIOR III' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT 'Tommy' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT 'Billy' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT NULL AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT ' ' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT '    JOHN  JACOB     SMITH' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT ' DR  SANJAY       GUPTA' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT 'DR JOHN S HOPKINS' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT ' MRS  SUSAN ADAMS' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual
                                UNION
                                SELECT ' MS AUGUSTA  ADA   SMITH-KING ' AS full_name
                                  FROM dual) raw_data) test_data) title) first_name
```

Answer (score -2):

Select SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name, ' ')+1) AS lastname,
  SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name, ' ')-1) AS firstname
  from whatever;