# MySQL: How to separate a name field in one table into firstname / lastname in two separate tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a drupal database where the `node` table is full of profiles.  The field `node.title` is "Firstname Lastname".  I want to separate the names so that `node.title` = "Firstname", and over in another table entirely, `content_type_profile.field_lastname_value` = "Lastname".  The entries in the two tables can be joined on the field `nid`.

I'd love to run a SQL command to do this, and I am fine with taking the naive approach that the first word is the first name, and everything else in the field is last name -- it will mean a few manual corrections down the line, but that's much better than doing it all by hand in the first place.

(I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/how-can-i-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-full-name-field-in-sql) and surely the answer lies in there but I am not that SQL-savvy and am not sure how to make it work for my database.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace 'John Smith' with the actual column name from your table, but this should give you the general idea.

```
select substring('John Smith',1,instr('John Smith',' ')-1) first_name; 

select substring('John Smith',instr('John Smith',' ')+1) last_name;
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a complete working example. I did it on Oracle since I don't have drupal, but hopefully the syntax should be similar.

```
CREATE TABLE content_type_profile (nid number,field_lastname_value VARCHAR2(20));
CREATE TABLE node (nid number,title VARCHAR2(20))

DELETE FROM node;
INSERT INTO node VALUES (1, 'John Smith');
INSERT INTO node VALUES (2, 'Jane Doe');

DELETE FROM content_type_profile;
INSERT INTO content_type_profile VALUES (1,NULL);
INSERT INTO content_type_profile VALUES (2,NULL);

UPDATE content_type_profile c
   SET field_lastname_value =
      (SELECT SUBSTR(n.title,instr(n.title,' ')+1)
         FROM node n
        WHERE n.nid = c.nid);

SELECT * FROM content_type_profile;
// returns 2 rows, one for Smith and one for Doe

UPDATE node
   SET title = SUBSTR(title,1,instr(title,' ')-1);

SELECT * FROM node;
// returns 2 rows, one for John and one for Jane
```

Comment: OK, so I use "select substring(node.title,1,instr(node.title,' ')-1) first_name;"?  But then how do I make it insert that into another table?

Comment: I don't think you want to "insert", I think you want to "update". See above for complete example.

Comment: Perfect -- I had to add a few extra WHEREs to limit the effect, but it did exactly what I was hoping.  Thanks for the help!