# T-SQL Query Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in Database called Full Name and I want split that name as FirstName and LastName:

Here is an Example:

FullName
Sam Peter

I want this to be

```
FirstName   LastName
-------------------- 
Sam          Peter
```

But the Problem is Some of the columns in Database have Full Names Like this

```
FullName
--------
Sam George Jack Peter
Sam Adam Peter
```

I want this to be

```
FirstName           LastName
---------           --------
Sam George Jack     Peter
Sam Adam            Peter
```

How do I write T-SQL Query for this.

Thanks in Advance for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very thorough name parsing routine described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/how-can-i-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-full-name-field-in-sql/159760#159760). It handles your situation, along with much trickier cases like "Mr. Martin J Van Buren III".

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation in SQL Server is notoriously weak.

Your best bet is to do it in  your application layer.

For your example with more than 2 names, how do you know which fields those additional names go into?  Are you guaranteed they will always have only one last name?

Comment: In my Case I know that it has only one last name

Answer (score 0):

Found this on net (did not test it)

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([FullName]),1,FINDSTRING(REVERSE([FullName])," ",1)))
```

You can test it with

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([FullName]),1,FINDSTRING(REVERSE([FullName])," ",1)))
FROM Table
```

if it works you can then

```
UPDATE Table
SET LastName = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([FullName]),1,FINDSTRING(REVERSE([FullName])," ",1)))
```

I leave the exercise for the first name to you.

Comment: Not Working. But Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you just splitting at the last space?  If so this should work:

```
select 'Sam George Jack Peter' as FullName
into #names
union select 'Sam Adam Peter'

select LEFT(FullName,LEN(FullName)-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(FullName))) as FirstName
  ,RIGHT(FullName,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(FullName))-1) as LastName
from #names
```

EDIT:
To handle names with no spaces and put the FullName as LastName

```
select 'Sam George Jack Peter' as FullName
into #names
union select 'Sam Adam Peter'
union select 'Peter'

select  CASE 
            WHEN    CHARINDEX(' ',FullName) = 0 THEN ''
            ELSE    LEFT(FullName,LEN(FullName)-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(FullName)))
        END as FirstName
        ,CASE 
            WHEN    CHARINDEX(' ',FullName) = 0 THEN FullName
            ELSE    LTRIM(RIGHT(FullName,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(FullName))))
        END as LastName
from #names
```

Comment: But I have so many Columns like this So Do I need to write select for each record?

Comment: It is giving me following error:Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: @Sam, once you get the syntax right you can write user defined function and user that http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3348181/User-Defined-Functions-in-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2000.htm

Comment: @Sam, You probably have some full names that have no spaces in them thus you are ending up with RIGHT(FullName,-1) which is invalid.  Edited the response the handle this.