# Update GridView Column after databinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Can I update a gridview column's content after databind? The SQL column is a full name, and I need to display it as last name, first name, not first name last name, as it is now. I know that i can do this in sql, but it seems as though it is going to be kind of a pain ([SQL: parse the first, middle and last name from a fullname field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/how-can-i-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-full-name-field-in-sql)). I was just wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks

Ok, I figured it out... sorry.  In the event someone else needs this, I added a `OnRowDataBound="MailingList_RowDataBound"` event, and within that event handler, I have am going to use the following code (modified to parse the name):

```
public void MailingList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // Required to ignore the header/footer.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Get the Person's Name
            string name = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            //Add your JavaScript onClick event link.
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "LookupEmail('" + name + "')");
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Test";
        }
    }
```

Changing the "Test" to the correct values.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <span>
       <%# Eval("FullName").Split(' ')[0]%>
    </span>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surname">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <span>
       <%# Eval("FullName").Split(' ')[1]%>
    </span>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This should solve your problem. Assuming the column name is `FullName` in your database and the first name and surname are seperated with space, you can split those and bind each value to different columns in `GridView`.

Comment: If you are wanting the name to still be in one column you can still do this, just combine them together "<%# Eval("FullName").Split(' ')[1] + ", " + Eval("FullName").Split(' ')[0] %>"

Answer (score 2):

use itemtemplate

```
            <asp:GridView ID="tset" runat="server">
               <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"  Text='<%#GetFormattedName(Eval("full_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

and write GetFormattedName method in code behind to return a string however you want,

```
    protected string GetFormattedName(string fullName)
    {
          // you can split full name here and swap first name, last name
          // depending on how you store it in DB 
    }
```