# How to replace text in some cells of GridView after data binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that is assosiated with database. Here's a data binding:

```
protected void GridViewProgramms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = ((GridView) sender).SelectedIndex;
    var programid = ((GridView) sender).Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
    GridViewEx.RowEditing += GridViewEx_RowEditing;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = programid;
    GridViewEx.DataBind();
    ExcersicePanel.Visible = true;
    PanelAp.Visible = false;
}
```

Everything works fine, but I need to change some cells values in GridView after that. I need to rewrite every Cell in the last row. How to do this without affecting the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write your code(To change the cell text) in `RowDataBound` event of the gridview after data bind

Refer following link for more explanation

[Update GridView Column after databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593587/update-gridview-column-after-databinding)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridViewEx_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        label or textbox ddltype = (label or textbox)e.Row.FindControl("id");
        ddltype.text="ur text";
    }
}
```