# Extract first and last names from nvarchar data

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I parse the first, middle and last name from a full name field in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/how-can-i-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-full-name-field-in-sql)

Say I have some nvarchar data 'Joe Blogs'...

I need to be able to query the data to extract the first and last names.

```
firstname
----------
Joe

lastname
----------
Blogs
```

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Are you talking about a simple word splitting mechanism, or a function to semantically determine which part is the first name and which the last? What happens with the input string `Ponce de Leon`? Also, the title has nothing to do with the question's content...

Comment: Also have you [searched the archives](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]+extract+first+last+name)? As this is a very common question. Possibly one of the previous responses may answer your question - or if not - help you refine this one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a T-SQL function that splits a string, based on a delimiter, and returns the tokens (pieces). There are a number available, such as this one:

[T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)

Comment: That's a link to this question :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Perhaps Randy thought this was a question about recursion...

Comment: Whoops - I'm sorry. That's not exactly what I had in mind. I fixed the link. See the function by Andy Robinson.

Comment: Hmm I think that would just handle the simplest case. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/159760/119477) does a much more comprehensive job.