# SQL - First and last name from full name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field, in as SQL table, with the fullname of the users that shows the employee number and then the full name (20284 - JOAQUIM MIGUEL SAMPAIO PEREIRA)

I only want to show "JOAQUIM PEREIRA".

Right now am trying to use the following code:

```
SELECT left(NMSTRING, CHARINDEX(' ',NMSTRING,CHARINDEX(' ',NMSTRING,CHARINDEX(' ',NMSTRING)+1)+1)-1) +
substring(WFPROCATTRIB.NMSTRING, len(WFPROCATTRIB.NMSTRING)-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(WFPROCATTRIB.NMSTRING))+1, len(WFPROCATTRIB.NMSTRING))
FROM WHATEVER
```

And the result i am getting is: "20284 - JOAQUIM PEREIRA"

How can i remove the "20284 - " part?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I assume SQL Server. I can see TSQL syntax.

Comment: Consider using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/sql-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-fullname-field as a guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(50) = '20284 - JOAQUIM MIGUEL SAMPAIO PEREIRA'

SELECT substring(@sql, charindex('-', @sql) + 2, charindex(' ', substring(@sql, charindex('-', @sql) + 2, len(@sql)))) + ' ' + substring(@sql, LEN(@sql) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@sql)) + 2, LEN(@sql))
```

Comment: Hello.
This one did exactly what i needed.

Comment: I am glad to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

If the employee number is always five characters, you could simply do:

```
 select substring(NMString, 9, len(NMString))
```

Another method would be to use `charindex()`:

```
select substring(NMString,
                 charindex(' - ', NMString) + 3,
                 len(NMString)
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring to get the desired result

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(100) = '20284 - JOAQUIM PEREIRA'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Name, CHARINDEX('-', @Name) + 1, LEN(@Name))
```

**More examples**:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
  EmployeeDetails varchar(100)

 )

 INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES ('20284 - JOAQUIM PEREIRA'),
 ('123 - Name1') , ('12312344 - Some Other Name')

 SELECT SUBSTRING(EmployeeDetails, CHARINDEX('-', EmployeeDetails) + 1, LEN(EmployeeDetails)) FROM @TestTable
```

[DEMO - ON Stackexchange data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/514345)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit overkill, but should work for you:

```
--Declare table with example
DECLARE @WHATEVER TABLE (
    NMSTRING nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @WHATEVER VALUES
(N'20284 - JOAQUIM MIGUEL SAMPAIO PEREIRA'),
(N'20285 - JOAQUIM SAMPAIO PEREIRA'),
(N'20286 - JOAQUIM PEREIRA')

--Declare xml variable
DECLARE @xml xml

--Put data in xml variable
SELECT @xml = (
    SELECT CAST('<s><n>' + REPLACE(NMSTRING,' ','</n><n>') + '</n></s>' as xml)
    FROM @WHATEVER
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
```

The data in `@xml` will look like this:

```
<s>
  <n>20284</n>
  <n>-</n>
  <n>JOAQUIM</n>
  <n>MIGUEL</n>
  <n>SAMPAIO</n>
  <n>PEREIRA</n>
</s>
<s>
  <n>20285</n>
  <n>-</n>
  <n>JOAQUIM</n>
  <n>SAMPAIO</n>
  <n>PEREIRA</n>
</s>
<s>
  <n>20286</n>
  <n>-</n>
  <n>JOAQUIM</n>
  <n>PEREIRA</n>
</s>
```

Then run this

```
SELECT t.v.value('n[3]','nvarchar(max)') + ' ' +
        COALESCE(t.v.value('n[6]','nvarchar(max)'),t.v.value('n[5]','nvarchar(max)'),t.v.value('n[4]','nvarchar(max)'))
FROM @xml.nodes('/s') as t(v)
```

Output

```
JOAQUIM PEREIRA
JOAQUIM PEREIRA
JOAQUIM PEREIRA
```