# Split fullname into first and last name

Tags: t-sql

If I have a table with a column that contains fullnames such as:

```
fullname
------------
Joe Bloggs
Peter Smith
Mary Jones and Liz Stone
```

How can I retrieve the first and last name from each of the entries in the full name column  using SQL. I'm not worried about the second name in the 3rd entry in my  example i.e. Liz Stone.

So basically to retrieve

```
Firstname
---------
Joe
Peter
Mary

Lastname  
--------
Bloggs 
Smith
Jones
```

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: What about middle names, such as `John Phillips Souza` ?  Unless you are  certain that each name will only contain a single first and last name, this problem can be difficult.

Comment: Middle names not required:)

Comment: Sql Server 2016 introduces the STRING_SPLIT method.

Comment: Why `Jones` and `Stone` instead of `Jones`, `and`, `Liz`, `Stone`? Splitting strings is forgivable for simple names, surnames. In this case though it appears you have some serious problems, with multiple persons stored in the same row

Comment: i just don't need the second (partner's name) I can find everything I need with Mary Jones

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sadly this is not an uncommon issue - usually when someone creates a database with limited knoweldge. I have this exact same issue to face when i begin migrating data within my own project. Currently my only real solution is to ADHOC the offending entries.

Comment: @thegunner I have a similar issue to face myself. I did stumble upon [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/sql-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-fullname-field) solution a couple of years back. You might be able to modify it to suit your needs, however your use case is far from simple - I sympathise

Answer (score 27):

Here is a pre SQL Server 2016 method, which uses basic string functions to isolate the first and last names.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(fullname, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname) - 1) AS Firstname,     
       SUBSTRING(fullname,
                 CHARINDEX(' ', fullname) + 1,
                 LEN(fullname) - CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)) AS Lastname
FROM yourTable
```

Note that this solution assumes that the `fullname` column only contains a single first name and a single last name (i.e. no middle names, initials, etc.).

Comment: Firstname comes out ok, but the Last name also include the partner's name e.g. 'Jones and Liz Stone'

Comment: Breaking the `and` row into two records would probably require a custom function.  I would recommend cleaning up your data before bringing it into SQL Server if you really have such edge cases.

Comment: Could we just replace  the "AND" and whatever name is after it with a blank string in your last name sql ?

Comment: Could we just replace  the "AND" and whatever name is after it with a blank string in the sql section were you deduce the last name?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) > 0
           THEN SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, LEN(FullName) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName)))
           ELSE ''
       END AS FirstName,
       CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) > 0
           THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(FullName), 
                       1, 
                       CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName)) - 1))
           ELSE FullName
       END AS LastName
FROM(VALUES('Mary Anne Bloggs'), ('Joe Bloggs'), ('Bloggs')) AS T(FullName);
```

This version checks that there is a space in the full name to split on. If there isn't then the first name is set to an empty string and the full name is put into the surname. Also, reverse is employed to split on the last space when there is more than one space

Answer (score 4):

This is a slippery slope and there are no easy answers.  That said, consider the following

```
Declare @YourTable table (FullName varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Joe Bloggs'),
('Peter Smith'),
('Betty Jane Martinez'),
('Mary Jones and Liz Stone')


Select A.*
      ,FirstName = Pos1+case when Pos3 is not null then ' '+Pos2 else '' end
      ,LastName  = case when Pos3 is null then Pos2 else Pos3 end
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
    Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
     From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select substring(FullName,1,charindex(' and ',FullName+' and ')-1) as [*] For XML Path('')),' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
 ) B
```

Returns

```
FullName                    FirstName   LastName
Joe Bloggs                  Joe         Bloggs
Peter Smith                 Peter       Smith
Betty Jane Martinez         Betty Jane  Martinez
Mary Jones and Liz Stone    Mary        Jones
```

If it helps with the visual, the CROSS APPLY generates

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use this query to retrieve first and lastname

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(FULLNAME, 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', FULLNAME)>0 THEN CHARINDEX(' ', FULLNAME) - 1 ELSE LEN(FULLNAME) END ) AS Firstname,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(FULLNAME), 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FULLNAME))>0 THEN CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FULLNAME)) - 1 ELSE LEN(REVERSE(FULLNAME)) END ) ) AS Firstname
FROM HRMDESFO.EMPLOID
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3PZT.jpg)

Comment: If query result is a text it should be posted as **a text** and not as **a screenshot**

Comment: I noticed the Firstname Alias is used for both replacements. I was able to use your query but had to change the Alias for the second replacement AS Lastname

Answer (score 2):

**BigQuery: Standard SQL**

```
substr(name,1,STRPOS(name,' ')-1) as FirstName,

substr(name,STRPOS(name,' ')+1,length(name)) as LastName
```

Comment: While this answer is not wrong, it doesn't mention the SQL dialect used. String functions are very specific to SQL dialect: [SQL Dialects Reference/Functions and expressions/String functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Functions_and_expressions/String_functions)

Comment: I mentioned BigQuery: Standard Sql dialect in the heading.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  passemail,substring(passemail,1,instr(passemail,'@') - 1) as name ,
substring(passemail,instr(passemail,'@') + 1,length(passemail)) from passenger
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer to help others learn. Code only answers are considered impolite.

Answer (score 0):

For getting firstName

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FULLNAME,1,(LOCATE(' ',FULLNAME)))  AS FIRSTTNAME from EmployeeDetails;
```

FOR LASTNAME

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FULLNAME,(LOCATE(' ',FULLNAME)))  AS LASTNAME from EmployeeDetails;
```

SO

```
SELECT  SUBSTR(FULLNAME,1,(LOCATE(' ',FULLNAME)))  AS FIRSTTNAME, SUBSTR(FULLNAME,(LOCATE(' ',FULLNAME)))  AS LASTNAME from EmployeeDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(column_name,  POSITION(' ' IN column_name)-1)                     AS first_name,
  RIGHT(column_name, LENGTH(column_name) - POSITION(' ' IN column_name)) AS last_name
FROM table_name
```

Comment: column_name: is the column containing the names. table_name: is the name of the table from which the column_name is selected from

Comment: Please do your best to format your answer better by adding description.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(NAME,1,(LOCATE(NAME, ' '))) AS FIRSTTNAME
    , SUBSTR(NAME,(LOCATE(NAME, ' ')+1)) AS LASTNAME
FROM yourTABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(candidate_name, 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', candidate_name)>0   THEN CHARINDEX(' ', candidate_name) - 1   
ELSE LEN(candidate_name) END ) AS Firstname,
SUBSTRING(substring(candidate_name,CHARINDEX(' ', candidate_name)+1,LEN(candidate_name)), 1, 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', candidate_name)>1 THEN CHARINDEX(' ', substring(candidate_name,CHARINDEX(' ', candidate_name)+1,LEN(candidate_name))) 
ELSE null END ) AS middle_name,
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(candidate_name), 1, 
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(candidate_name))>0 
 THEN CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(candidate_name)) - 1
 ELSE null END ) )AS last_name
FROM  Test_name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

*So first we have to find the index for space(" ") because space is the character which is separating the two words ( first_name+" "+last_name).
In my case, its mid_index is a variable that stores the index for space(" ").*

```
SELECT primary_poc, STRPOS(fullname,' ') AS "mid_index"
   FROM yourTable_name
```

*Now we will use min_index to find the left and right sides of words. For this, we can use a subquery.
Below is the final query *

```
SELECT fullname,
LEFT(fullname, mid_index - 1) AS "first_name",
RIGHT(fullname, LENGTH(primary_poc) - mid_index) AS "last_name"
FROM
(
   SELECT primary_poc, STRPOS(fullname,' ') AS "mid_index"
   FROM yourTable_name
) AS t1
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include a description of what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

FOR SQL SERVER

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(fullname, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)) AS FirstName
    ,SUBSTRING(fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname), LEN(fullname)) AS LastName
FROM [YourTable]
```

If your full name has another delimiter aside from space, such as dashes, you substitute in the dash e.g

```
SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(fullname, 0, CHARINDEX('-', fullname)) AS FirstName
        ,SUBSTRING(fullname, CHARINDEX('-', fullname), LEN(fullname)) AS LastName
    FROM [YourTable]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: this is my first fullname column]
[image: this is my final output with firstname and lastname]

In Postgres SQL

```
SELECT fullname,
SUBSTRING(fullname, 1, POSITION(' ' IN fullname) - 1) as first_name  ,
SUBSTRING(fullname,(position(' 'in fullname)))  AS lastname from details;
```

Answer (score 0):

--This works for data which may have a middle name, middle initial or just a first and last name. I am not dealing with suffixes (i.e. Jr, Sr, III, etc) and I am assuming data is always first, middle, last. The answer box doesn't like CTE's so I am submitting it with a subquery.

```
SELECT [payerName],
       frst, scnd, thrd,
       LEFT(payerName, CHARINDEX(' ', payerName)) AS FirstName,
       CASE WHEN Scnd > 0 
           THEN SUBSTRING(payerName, frst + 1, scnd - frst) 
           ELSE '' END AS MiddleName,
       CASE WHEN Scnd = 0 THEN SUBSTRING(payerName, thrd + 1, 50)
           ELSE SUBSTRING(payerName, scnd + 1, 50)
           END AS LastName
    FROM (
        SELECT [payerName],
           LEFT(payerName, CHARINDEX(' ', payerName)) AS FirstName,
           CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(payerName)) AS Frst,
           CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(payerName), CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(payerName))+1) AS Scnd,
           CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(payerName), CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(payerName)) + CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(payerName), CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(payerName))+1)) AS Thrd
        FROM [AccountDeduction]
    ) rex
```

Result:

payerName          frst scnd  thrd  FirstName MiddleName LastName

Grant E Corbin        6    8     0  Grant     E          Corbin

Alcena Winston        7    0     7  Alcena               Winston

Jeff Crosby           5    0     5  Jeff                 Crosby

Carolyn Tillage       8    0     8  Carolyn              Tillage

Answer (score 0):

For DB2, below is the method that result first and last names use a column that contain full name.

```
select
a.USER as "User Name",
a.FULL_NAME as "Full Name",
substr(a.FULL_NAME, 1, instr(a.FULL_NAME, ' ')) as "First Name",
substr(a.FULL_NAME, instr(a.FULL_NAME, ' ', 1, round((length(a.FULL_NAME) - length(replace(a.FULL_NAME, ' ', ''))) / length(' '))), 20) as "Last Name"
from PROFILES a
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest and shortest to this question without any assumptions. Also you can even further enhance this with a `rtrim(ltrim('firstname lastname'))`.

Just in case of any spaces before the strings,

```
Select 
    substring('Firstname Lastname',1,CHARINDEX(' ', 'Firstname Lastname')) as firstname, 
    substring('Firstname Lastname',CHARINDEX(' ', 'Firstname Lastname'),LEN('Firstname Lastname')) as Lastname
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use,

```
 STRING_SPLIT (string , separator)
```

Comment: This should be a comment. If you want to post this as an answer, you should post an actual example. How is the OP going to access the surname?

Comment: or in the case also mentioned of "mr smith and mrs jane" or "Alex smith and alice jane"