# split a fullname into first, middle, last and suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have full_name column data like

```
|Victoria Brown  |
|Sam Allen JR    |
|Ray M James III |
```

I want to split base on the number of space the fistname, lastname
HERE is what I did but last case statement is coming wrong it still getting the suffix when we have 3 space. also need to combinne them into one column please.

Comment: Good luck.  Some last names, like mine, contain a blank character,

Comment: Dr. Mary Joan De La Hoya - Mc Donalds III Jr, MD
name can have salutaion (Dr), multiple first/middle names, last names may have prefixes (Mc, O, Della, etc), names can be doubled, there can be multiple suffixes (generational, professional, etc)

Comment: @DaleK I have tried this but the last case statement isn't coming correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately a lot more complex than it may first seem, and how you handle it may have to do largely with the end goal for the data.

Here's a post that covers this same issue in fairly great depth -
[SQL: parse the first, middle and last name from a fullname field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/sql-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-fullname-field)

As Gilbert pointed out, some names are just different, and it will be hard to get everything right, but there are certainly things you can do to limit errors.

One of the better pieces of advice from that article would be to alter your collection method to get First/Middle/Last/Suffixes/Prefixes entered separately and join them after, rather than try to parse through richer text that contains them all.

Here is a function that you could get creative with - https://blog.seandaylor.com/sql-server-split-part/

Comment: Not really an answer, more like suggested reading which should be in a comment.

Comment: Understandable, not sure that it would have fit in the character limit

Comment: I am close to what I need actually. thanks